# IEnumerable has values but still gives System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, telerik-reporting

I am populating an `IEnumerable` using a LINQ query.  The `IEnumerable` is then passed into another class and appended as a parameter (to a Telerik report).  On this line, I'm getting a `System.NullReferenceException`.  Through debugging I've confirmed that this `IEnumerable` has a list of values so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Here are some relevant snippets of my code:

**Class1.cs**

```
//Note that divisionList is an List of PKs and divisionTotalsList is a list of DivisionTotalsModel
foreach (int division in divisionList)
            {

                //LINQ Query
                IEnumerable<DivisionTotalsModel> divSubset =
                    from divno in divisionTotalsList
                    where divno.DivisionNo == division
                    select divno;


                //Create Report
                if(divSubset.Any())
                    Class2.DoStuff(divSubset);
            }
```

**Class2.cs**

```
public void DoStuff(IEnumerable<DivisionTotalsModel> divisionList){
     using (var divisionTotalsReport = new DivisionReport())
        {
          //There are other parameters here that are working successfully
          //This is the line that is failing
          divisionTotalsReport.ReportParameters["list"].Value = divisionList;
        }
}
```

Why is the error occurring here?

The `ReportParameters` are working with other parameters (`DateTime` and `int`), I just didn't include them in the code snippet.

I've tried `ToList()` and successfully received a `List<T>`, but Telerik requires an `IEnumerable<T>`.

**The issue has to lie with the new parameter** because I've been able to successfully create the report previously using my other parameters (`DateTime` and `int`).  The issue has only started when I've tried to add this new `IEnumerable` parameter.

I've gone through the debugger and looked at the IEnumerable, it says the base is null but when I go to non public members -> source I can see the items.

**Solution**

I've figured out the problem, I was attempting to feed the data source as a parameter. I've set it as the data source instead and it works perfectly.

Comment: Perhaps you could add the piece of code that initializes `ReportParameters` ?

Comment: Debug the code and see what is actually `null` on that line of code.  It's probably not `divisionList`.  Odds are that either `ReportParameters` is `null` or (probably more likely) whatever it's indexer returns is `null`.

Comment: Have you tried use `.ToArray` in linq?

Comment: Have you checked that `divisionTotalsReport`, `divisionTotalsReport.ReportParameters`, and `divisionTotalsReport.ReportParameters["list"]` are all valid instantiated objects?

Comment: @Deanna yes, I've been able to successfully create a report with other parameters.  The issue therefore must lie with the new parameter.

Comment: When writing inline code, use the back-tick (`) around the code segments to set them apart from standard text.

Comment: @user1287523 Don't guess.  *We* have to, since we don't have the ability to actually check, but you can just debug the program and *know* which null reference is being accessed; you don't need to guess.

Comment: @Servy I'm debugging it right now and have set a breakpoint before the point of failure.  `divisionTotalsReport` is not null.  `ReportParameters` are also not null.  It might be `ReportParameters["list"]` though.... I'll have to look further.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you add a `ReportParameter` named "list" to the report before setting its value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line, not just `divisionList` can be `null`, and in fact, in this case, it would be fine.

```
divisionTotalsReport.ReportParameters["list"].Value = divisionList
```

As the `NullReferenceException` exception only normally occurs when trying to dereference an object, the candidates are:

1. `divisionTotalsReport`
2. `divisionTotalsReport.ReportParameters`
3. `divisionTotalsReport.ReportParameters["list"]`

If you've confirmed that `divisionTotalsReport` is set and that `ReportParameters` is returning a valid reference, then it is most likely that it just doesn't have a `list` item.

You don't show what initialises `DivisionReport` but if it's loaded from a report file, you may need to add the `list` parameter before you can set it.